# React - Overwrite part of the state.object's values whilst preserving the old ones.

Tags: reactjs

Lets say I have the following object saved in the components state:

```
quiz_object : {
   'title': 'math questions', 
   'description': 'lots of text',
   'question': 'x + y =?', 
   'answer': '4!'
}
```

This component serves to edit 'quiz_objects'. Edit fields pas a 'name' and a 'value' to the update function. (For example: when editting the title field to 'Test edit' the 'name' would be 'title' . and the 'value' would be 'Test edit')

```
this.setState ((prevState) =>({
            ['quiz_object']: {[name]: value}
    }));
```

The code above correctly sets the new title, but seems to overwrite the entire old object, leaving me with the following state:

```
quiz_object: {
   'title': 'Test edit',
}
```

Is there a way to peform partial edits on (nested) state objects whilst preserving the old data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can spread (or `Object.assign`) the existing values:

```
this.setState ((prevState) =>({
        quiz_object: { ...prevState.quiz_object, [name]: value }
}));
```

Using `Object.assign` (use this if you can't use object spread):

```
this.setState ((prevState) =>({
        quiz_object: Object.assign(prevState.quiz_object, {[name]: value})
}));
```

However, you can also send just the object, no need to use an updater function in this case:

```
this.setState({ quiz_object: { ...this.state.quiz_object, [name]: value} });
```

So the above code will preserve the `quiz_object` properties on `state` only changing `[name]`.

**note: underscores are ok for variable names in JavaScript :)

Comment: Both the spread operator and the Object assign method work great, thanks for helping me solve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can create new `quiz_object` using spread-syntax `...` to get old object properties and assign new one and then setState with that object.

```js
class A extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      quiz_object: {
        'title': 'math questions',
        'description': 'lots of text',
        'question': 'x + y =?',
        'answer': '4!'
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let newObj = { ...this.state.quiz_object, title: 'Test edit'}
    this.setState({quiz_object: newObj})
  }

  render() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state, 0, 4))
    return null;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( 
  <A /> ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Both the spread operator and the Object assign method work great, thanks for helping me solve the problem!