# React fetch data before render class component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, axios, react-hooks

I have tried every option i can find myself but i am not understanding what am i doing wrong.
My axios get data update but when i use conditions it always render the first state data. this is my code.

```
    import axios from 'axios';
import React, { Component,  } from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class ProtectedRoute extends Component{
  // _isMounted = false;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        Authenticated: undefined
    };
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    // this._isMounted = true;
        axios.get('/api/get_me')
        .then(res => {
          if (this._isMounted) {
            if (res.data.logged_in == true) {
              this.setState({Authenticated: true});
              console.log(this.state.Authenticated)
            }
          }
        })
        .catch(err =>{
          this.setState({Authenticated: false});
        });
    }
    // componentWillUnmount() {
    //   this._isMounted = false;
    // }
    render(){
        const { component: Component, ...props } = this.props;
        const Authenticated = this.state;
        console.log(Authenticated)
        if (Authenticated == true) {
          return(<Route {...props} render={props => (<Component {...props} />)}/>)
        }
        else{
          return(<Redirect to='/login' />)
        }
        // return (
        //   <Route 
        //     {...props} 
        //     render={props => (
        //       Authenticated ?
        //         <Component {...props} /> :
        //         <Redirect to='/login' />
        //     )} 
        //   />
        // )
    }
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

whenever i use condition it goes with **undefined** value. i want to use class component not functional hooks. I don't understanding **what am i doing wrong and what can i do to solve this problem?** I have tried all the comment section codes but not solved.
this is the error.
[image]

Comment: `if (this._isMounted)` - where do you set the flag to `true`? It looks commented out everywhere

Comment: You have two console logs with Authenticated, how do you know which is which in the error output?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova it always render first state as you can see in the console that it  is showing undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the name property. Since its an object, so you must call it like this. else it will return undefined.

```
const Authenticated = this.state.Authenticated
```

Comment: Showing undefined

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct **destructuring**

```
const Authenticated = this.state;
```

**correct** one

```
const { Authenticated } = this.state;
```

or
assign like this

```
const Authenticated = this.state.Authenticated ;
```

Check this out for better understanding of [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to uncomment `// this._isMounted = true;` for `componentWillMount` and the `_isMounted = false` on line 7.

You are getting an undefined on `Authenticated` state because your API might be resolving but `this._isMounted` is undefined as you have commented them out.

You'll need to properly get your Authenticated state too with proper destructuring as mentioned by the other answers.
const { Authenticated } = this.state;

So regarding your response where you do not want to redirect while waiting for the response of your API. You might want to add a loading state. This way, your app shows something while waiting for your API to resolve & not redirect.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    Authenticated: undefined
    isLoading: true,
  };
}

componentWillMount(){
  this._isMounted = true;
  axios.get('/api/get_me')
    .then(res => {
      if (this._isMounted) {
        if (res.data.logged_in == true) {
          this.setState({Authenticated: true});
          console.log(this.state.Authenticated)
        }
      }
     })
     .catch(err =>{
       this.setState({Authenticated: false});
     })
     .finally(() => {
       this.setState({ isLoading: false });
     });
}

render(){
    const { component: Component, ...props } = this.props;
    const {Authenticated, isLoading} = this.state;
    console.log(Authenticated)

    if(isLoading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
    if (Authenticated == true) {
      return(<Route {...props} render={props => (<Component {...props} />)}/>)
    }
    else{
      return(<Redirect to='/login' />)
    }
    // return (
    //   <Route 
    //     {...props} 
    //     render={props => (
    //       Authenticated ?
    //         <Component {...props} /> :
    //         <Redirect to='/login' />
    //     )} 
    //   />
    // )
}
```

Comment: i have shared these codes with comment so that all can understand that i have used them but not solved my problem. Let me tell you once again i get all my data correctly but when i use condition like if auth== true then go anywhere. but when i render it, it goes with first state undefined then after render it comes true. but my condition already rendered.

Comment: Ahh, so do you mean when you navigate to your ProtectedRoutes, it goes undefined initially instead? then goes to true later on when your fetch has been resolved, is that right?

Comment: yes but it goes redirect to login page i want to take some time to render to show or redirect

Comment: Alright, so here's a workaround. You can add a loading state to your state instead while waiting for your response. you create a Loading component that you show while waiting for `axios.get('/api/get_me')`

Comment: I've added some more context to what I mean. Let me know if it helps! @CoderBoy

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked what your state looks like after the setting of the state happens in the finally block? Are you sure you are not overwriting the other values?

Try using the spread operator to retain every value in the state:
[React - Overwrite part of the state.object's values whilst preserving the old ones.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791704/react-overwrite-part-of-the-state-objects-values-whilst-preserving-the-old-on)

Also, I think componentWillMount is really not recommended any more, here is official guidance on safer versions to replace it with:

https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for an answer on how to load data via `fetch()` and then only render data after the data is returned.

Finally figured it out so I thought I'd write it up.

```
export class StoryGrid extends React.Component {

  constructor(props: String) {
    super(props);
    // set initial state value to indicate that data hasn't been loaded
    this.state = { remoteDataIsLoaded: false };
  }

  render() {
    // The target component (which holds the fetched data) will only 
    // render if the state variable is true
    if (this.state.remoteDataIsLoaded) {
       return (<LibreGrids allGridData={this.allGridData}/>);
    }
    else{ 
       // otherwise the user will see the loading message.
       return (<h2>Loading data...</h2>);
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.remoteDataIsLoaded === false) {
       // using star wars api
       fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people")
       .then (result => result.json())
       .then (data => { 
           //do somethin with data["results"];
           // Done fetching data so make it so this code isn't called again
           this.setState({
            remoteDataIsLoaded: true,
          });
       })
       .catch(error => {
          console.log(`couldn't get data! : ${error}`);
          console.log(`Will continue without remote data.`);
          // still insure that this isn't loaded so you don't get into infinite loop
          this.setState({
            remoteDataIsLoaded: true,
          });
        });
    } 
}
```

### Code Explanation

1. When the Component loads the constructor will set the state variable `remoteDataIsLoaded = false`
2. The component will run the `render()` method, but since the state variable is false the user will see the loading message.
3. After render() runs, then `componentDidMount()` will run.
4. Since the state variable is false, the `fetch()` call will run to get the data.
5. if the data is retrieved successfully, then the state variable (`remoteDataIsLoaded`) is set to true so the component's `render()` method will be called again.  (Changing a state variable value causes React to fire the `render()` method again.)
6. In this simple case even if there is an error during `fetch()` and the `catch()` method is hit then we set the state variable to true because it means that the data couldn't be fetched anyways.  Your target component should indicate that data wasn't loaded.  Here I just write to console.